# How to get the source collection of ICollectionView preserving the sort order?

Tags: c#, wpf, sorting, collectionview, collectionviewsource

In my `WPF` application, I have an `ICollectionView` that I use to display a list of data in a data grid after filtering and sorting. Once I do the filtering and sorting the way I like, I would like to export the source collection ***preserving the sort order***.

I can get my underlying source collection after filtering like so:

```
var items = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyICollectionView).SourceCollection.Cast<MyItemType>();
```

This returns my filtered items just fine, but it loses the sorted order.
How do I get the filtered list preserving the order as well?

I know I can get the sort descriptions like below:

```
var sortDescriptions = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(MyICollectionView).SortDescriptions;
```

But that merely returns the sort properties in string format, which won't help me in my case.

Comment: var preservedSorting = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Control.ItemsSource); Control here is the itemscontrol that you bound the collection "MyICollectionView" to. Also GetDefaultView has its own snapshot of sorted or filtered collection.

Comment: This worked great, thanks! If you post this as an answer I can accept.

Comment: why do you have the CollectionViewSource at all? You bind regular collection sorted in any way, and ObservableCollection will auto-refresh if you change the items. Library like [DynamicData](https://github.com/reactiveui/DynamicData) takes care of that while staying perofrmant

Comment: @KrzysztofSkowronek because I need to do some filtering as well.

Comment: Take a look at that library I linked - it has a list that you declare with LINQ like usually, but it's reactive and refreshes the result when source collection changes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(Control.ItemsSource);
```

Control here is the itemscontrol that you bound the collection "MyICollectionView" to. For more information check out [how-to-get-the-default-view-of-a-data-collection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/data/how-to-get-the-default-view-of-a-data-collection)

Comment: This worked great. Just to complete the answer; in my case I use the `MVVM` pattern, so in the VM instead of referring to `Control` you can use whatever the enumerable you're using as the items source.